# copy only one column if criteria is met (Need to adjust my existing code)

Tags: vba, excel

The below code works great for copying an entire row, how do I make it so I only copy over the first column.

I have tried altering range with no success? Condition is in J, the only column to copy should be 1st one.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 1

For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("J1:J" & lastRow)
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets(5).Cells(i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Many thanks!

Comment: cell.EntireRow.Copy Change to cells(cell.row,1).Copy

Comment: With the first column, do you mean column "A" in excel?

Comment: Yes I do thanks, copy only column A when criteria in J are met

Comment: Thanks guys, all sorted! @99moorem

Comment: @user4242750 Could you mark the answer below as answered if the code is doing what you would like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switch `EntireRow` to `EntireColumn`, it is as simple as that! ;)

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 1

For Each rCell In Sheets(1).Range("J1:J" & lastRow)
    If rcell.Value = 1 Then
        rcell.EntireColumn.Copy Sheets(5).Cells(1, i)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next rCell
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 1

For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("J1:J" & lastRow)
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cells(cell.row,1).Copy Sheets(5).Cells(i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long    
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 1

For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("J1:J" & lastRow)
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.End(xlToLeft).Copy Sheets(5).Cells(i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```